# MongoDB project part of the array element

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a projection where I can take just part of a Array element.

Take this document as a model:

```
{
    "city_info": {
        "name": "First City"
        "initials": "FC"
    },
    "postal_codes": {
        "ranges": [
            {
                "name": "Range 1",
                "details": "More details",
                "another_object": {
                   (...)
                },
                "codes": [
                    {"code": 1},
                    {"code": 2},
                    {"code": 3}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Range 2",
                "details": "More details 2",
                "another_object": {
                   (...)
                }
                "codes": [
                    {"code": 4},
                    {"code": 5}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My query would look like `{"postal_codes.ranges.codes.code": 3}`

Ranges and codes can have hundreads of elements. "another_object" is just a placeholder used for example.

The expected return would be like:

```
{
    "city_info": {
        "name": "First City"
        "initials": "FC"
    },
    "range": {
        "name": "Range 1",
        "details": "More details",
        "another_object": {
            (...)
        }
    }         
}
```

In short, I need to get the array element that matches the query too, but do not return it entirely.

It seems that find is not powerfull enough, I would need some kind of aggregation. I have tried to use a match to return only the documents that match the query, but I do not know how to project only part of the array.

Comment: Your JSON structure is not valid. `"codes": [
                    "code": 4,
                    "code": 5
                ]` should be `"codes": [{
                    "code": 4,
                    "code": 5
                }]`. Isn't?

Comment: Well noticed, I fixed it to an array of objects with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid `codes` structure. This cannot be inserted in Mongodb

```
"codes": [
  "code": 1,
  "code": 2,
  "code": 3
]
```

If you need to keep three codes, valid JSON would be

```
"codes": [
  1,2,3
]
```

So sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f074307e96d8884b6bdbdd5"),
    "city_info" : {
        "name" : "First City",
        "initials" : "FC"
    },
    "postal_codes" : {
        "ranges" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Range 1",
                "details" : "More details",
                "another_object" : {},
                "codes" : [ 
                    1, 
                    2, 
                    3
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Range 2",
                "details" : "More details 2",
                "another_object" : {},
                "codes" : [ 
                    4, 
                    5
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Query to get:

```
db.getCollection('test2').aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$postal_codes.ranges"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$postal_codes.ranges.codes"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "postal_codes.ranges.codes": 3
    }
  }

])
```

Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f074307e96d8884b6bdbdd5"),
    "city_info" : {
        "name" : "First City",
        "initials" : "FC"
    },
    "postal_codes" : {
        "ranges" : {
            "name" : "Range 1",
            "details" : "More details",
            "another_object" : {},
            "codes" : 3
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid `codes` in the output, you need to use `$project` as last pipeline

```
{
 $project:{"postal_codes.ranges.codes":0}
}
```

Comment: in this how do we get the first matching element only? i.e wherever it matches 3 just return it and project it along with other required properties from the document.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [$unwind](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZzpKnzMDqAhVZT30KHaNyAVAQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.com%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Foperator%2Faggregation%2Funwind&usg=AOvVaw0wP4P3e7aYOC1JPY9ffHBM) to convert **Array** into **Objects** and then use [$match](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiemNrBzMDqAhWFUn0KHWCnBpYQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.com%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Foperator%2Faggregation%2Fmatch&usg=AOvVaw1aRuWiVng7g_LXoSKF6JA0)

Try this query,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$postal_codes" },
  { "$unwind": "$postal_codes.ranges.codes"},
  { "$match" : { "postal_codes.ranges.codes" : { "$eq": 3 } }},
  { "$project" : { "city_info": 1, "ranges": "$postal_codes.ranges" }}
])
```

Hope, this may help you.